# How to capture my screen with python properly?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-3.5, opencv

I try to capture my screen using python and see any movement in my screen. The screen is been captured always and updated. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab

while(True):
    screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,40,800,640)))

    cv2.imshow('window', cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

And this is the result (kind of nesting images inside..):
[image]

So.. where am I wrong in the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're capturing the part of the screen which displays the output too. If you don't want to view the output, remove `cv2.imshow('window', cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))`. Otherwise move the output screen out of the capture window.
Refer to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ks4MPfMq8aQ). This guys(Sentdex) uses a similar method to capture screen to create a neural network to play GTA5(much later).

Comment: That is my problem. Not only it is simillar - it is the exact method. But I have different result, while he got the 'good' result.

Comment: Just move the window you're trying to capture to the foreground? Like he did at 10:48 in the video.

Comment: No worries, happy to help. :)

Comment: As I went through his tutorial I could not understand one point : 1-8 parts he used Hough Lines and such. As I understand - In the next parts (9-13) he does not even use the previous parts. Basically he trains the neuronal network without the hough lines?

Comment: Yeah, he did that. I'm not sure about the parts involving neural networks as I haven't watched that part yet

Comment: So he did not even use actual image processing? Just left behind the whole image processing he did in in parts 1-8? Just want to be sure

Comment: Like I said, I'm not sure because I haven't watched it yet. I'll do so soon. I'll let you know when I do

Comment: I'm watching the videos now, and yes, he discarded it all and is starting fresh for neural networks.